# Saving Bitmap failed error when trying to export a image in the IDE

Tags: delphi, ide, firemonkey

I have a `TImage`, which has its own subcomponent `MultiResBitmap` which also has a "0 - Normal" subcomponent. When accessing the Bitmap Editor of the 3rd component and using the "Save" option, I am prompted to select a location in which to save the file. After entering that I'm given a "Saving Bitmap failed" error.

I tried extracting the needed image from the programs resource file, but it did not show anything except the programs icon when using Resource Hacker

How can extract that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this maybe it will work

```
Image1.MultiResBitmap[0].Bitmap.SaveToFile('delphi_img.png');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.